# Geo location - how does it work?

Tags: c#, android, iphone, titanium

Example I get the "Latitude" and "longitude" GEO location of the 6 mobile device: A,B,C,D,E,F
(devices are either iphone, ipad, android etc)

Now how do I find all devices within the radius of 10 meters, in range of device A?
(just an example) is there a library I could use?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the distance between A and the other locations, then filter out the ones that are too far? On Android there is [this helpful method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29), similar ones probably exist on other platforms. You can always implement the underlying math in your app as well.

Comment: thanks, ...I will have to do the calculations on the server which is written in C#. So would need a library in c#.

Comment: You might want to specify this in your question explicitly and maybe change the title -- it's way too vague. BTW, Android is open source so you can always look at the code and port it to C# if all else fails.

Answer (score 1):

as for the math...  this site has some details on calculating various things to do with lat/long

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use following method for finding distance between two latitude-longitude,

```
public static float calculateDistance (float lat1, float lng1, float lat2, float lng2 ) 
{
    double earthRadius = 3958.75;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
    Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    double dist = earthRadius * c;

    int meterConversion = 1609;

    return new Float(dist * meterConversion).floatValue();
}
```